# File Access Info and How to Password protect a folder

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory

One of our HR girls put a file in an open directory that everyone could see. We know an employee or employees looked at this info and stole some of the info. Is there away to see what users accessed a file or folder? All are employees log in under a terminal server.

Question 2.

My owner thinks there is a way to password protect a file. I have never seen this besides putting something in a zip or using a program. Does anyone know of a different way?

Thanks
GA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to see what users accessed a file or folder in Windows, **if** you have object access auditing set up ahead of time.

Since you did not have that set up, then no.

You can use AD Rights Management Services (AD RMS) for the type of document protection you're looking for.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/protecting-a-word-document-with-ad-rms.aspx

Comment: thanks for the comments. How do u set up object access and auditing?

Comment: @user160605 It's a two-part process. First, you enable the policy setting, second, you modify the SACL on the object/objects on which you want to audit access. The exact process is shown here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399

Answer (score 1):

You can view when a file was last accessed, but not by whom in a default Windows installation.

You cannot "password protect" a folder in a Windows environment. What you need to do is setup the correct permissions on the folder to restrict/allow access.

If you don't want to bother with proper folder permissions, you can password protect a Windows Compressed File. (ZIP file) But at the end of the day, that file can still be removed from the server, and taken off site for whatever purposes.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306531/en-gb